# Some variable for each lines SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL Database , I want for each lines SQL, sum variable for one colum.

My request (works):

```
SELECT * FROM test "WHERE
DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%Y-%m-%d')=DATE(NOW())";
```

For each line, CONSO is the name of 1 column :

```
(CONSO + CONSO + CONSO + CONSO +...) * 12
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Do you mean horizontally adding the values in several different columns? Yes then you just do x + y + z as computation. What are you asking?

Comment: People will give you answers,as long as you don't have to be an astrologer to understand the question.

Comment: It's for each line of SQL request, I want to sum all values of 1 column.
example: CONSO (column) : 50 (line1), 10 (line2), 21 (line3),...

Comment: Why did you put the opening quote halfway through the query?

Comment: I use this query in PHP file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up all the CONSO values, and multiply the sum by 12:

```
SELECT sum(conso) * 12
  FROM test
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE(NOW());
```

To sum up all the CONSO values, each multiplied by 12:

```
SELECT sum(conso * 12) 
  FROM test
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE(NOW());
```

Comment: Thanks ShWiVeL ! How to display the result or use $variable ?

Comment: Are you summing a column or a variable? We were under the assumption that CONSO is the column of a table in your database called test

Comment: It's a column. But how to save the result in variable ?

Comment: @gloops100 You need to create a new question for that. We don't write code for you here.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
 SELECT SUM(CONSO) AS consoTotal FROM test WHERE [condition]
```

You might be able to multiply by 12 there as well - I haven't tried it.....

Comment: Tkanks for you answer :) . Is it possible to do this for 2 variables ? (CONSO_1 & CONSO_2) like this : SELECT SUM(CONSO_1) AS condoTotal_1 SUM(CONSO_2) AS consoTotal_2 FROM test WHERE [condition]

Comment: You can multiply by 12 there as per ShWiVeL's answer below

Comment: Yes it is possible to have multiple SUMs

Comment: Like this : SELECT SUM(CONSO_1) AS condoTotal_1 SUM(CONSO_2) AS consoTotal_2 FROM test WHERE [condition] ?

Comment: I think what you need is `GROUP BY`

Comment: Just add a comma (,) after AS consoTotal_1.

Comment: What benefit is GROUP BY in this context Dipendu?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT Conso, SUM(Conso)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Conso
WHERE your_condition
```